# Pixel access in OpenCV 2.2

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, pixel

Hi I want to use opencv to tell me the pixel values of a blank and white image 
so the output would look like this

```
10001
00040
11110   
00100
```

Here is my current code but I'm not sure how to access the results of the `CV_GET_CURRENT` call.. any help ?

```
IplImage readpix(IplImage*  m_image) {


  cout << "Image width  : " << m_image->width << "\n"; 
  cout << "Image height : " << m_image->height << "\n"; 
  cout << "-----------------------------------------\n"; 


  CvPixelPosition8u position;

  CV_INIT_PIXEL_POS(position, (unsigned char*)(m_image->imageData), m_image->widthStep, cvSize(m_image->width, m_image->height), 0, 0, m_image->origin);

  for(int y = 0; y < m_image->height; ++y) // FOR EACH ROW
  {
    for(int x = 0; x < m_image->width; ++x) // FOR EACH COL 
      {
        CV_MOVE_TO(position, x, y, 1);
        unsigned char colour = *CV_GET_CURRENT(position, 1);

// I want print 1 for a black pixel or 0 for a white pixel 
// so i want goes here


      }

  cout << " \n"; //END OF ROW

  }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In opencv 2.2, I'd use the C++ interface.

```
cv::Mat in = /* your image goes here, 
                assuming single-channel image with 8bits per pixel */
for(int row = 0; row < in.rows; ++row) {
    unsigned char* inp  = in.ptr<unsigned char>(row);
    for (int col = 0; col < in.cols; ++col) {
        if (*inp++ == 0) {
            std::cout << '1';
        } else {
            std::cout << '0';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the same be done using IplImage.?? If so, could you please throw some light upon..

Comment: @Frankenstein Andrews answer shows a way to to pixel access with IplImage.

Answer (score 2):

IplImage struct have a variable `char* imageData` - it's just a buffer of all pixels. To read it properly you have to know your image format. For example for RGB888 image 3 first chars in imageData array will represent the r,g,b values of the first pixel at the first row. If you know the image format - you can read the data properly. Image format can be restored reading another values of IplImage structure:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html

Also i think it's more efficient to write the loop like this:

```
uchar r,g,b;

for (int y = 0; y < cvFrame->height; y++)
{
    uchar *ptr = (uchar*) (cvFrame_->imageData + y*cvFrame_->widthStep);
    for (int x = 0; x < cvFrame_->width; x++)
    {       
        r = ptr[3*x];
        g = ptr[3*x + 1];
        b = ptr[3*x + 2];
    }
}
```

This code is for RGB888 image

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 2):

IplImage is the old format for images. You should use the new format, CvMat, which can store arbitrary matrices. An image is just a matrix, after all.

You can then access the pixels using the function [cvGet2D](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html#get-d), which returns a CvScalar.

Comment: Thanks I've just seen that in the 2.1 docs for Mat, I'll change to that,,,

Comment: Actually carnieri, is there any chance you can show me how its done using Mat, seem a lot has changed since the 1.* versions

Comment: cvMat version in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824787/opencv-multi-channel-elemnt-access

Comment: The answers there are way too complicated. `mat.at<unsigned char>(row, col)`