# Saving Mats into int arrays in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I split my img into 3 separate Mats like this:

```
std::vector<Mat> planes(3);
cv::split(img, planes);
cv::Mat R = planes[2];
cv::Mat G = planes[1];
cv::Mat B = planes[0];
```

Now I want to store these R, G and Bs values in three different arrays. Somthing like this:
for example for R.

```
std::vector<Mat> planes(3);
cv::split(img, planes);
cv::Mat R = planes[2];
int r[20]; 

for (i=0 ; i<20 ; i++)

{

r[i]= R[i];

}
```

I know this will give error. So how do I correctly implement this feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this for R (with obvious extension to B & G)

```
std::vector<Mat> planes(3);
cv::split(img, planes);
cv::Mat R;

// change the type from uchar to int
planes[2].convertTo(R, CV_32SC1);

// get a pointer to the first row
int* r = R.ptr<int>(0);

// iterate of all data  (R has to be continuous
// with no row padding to do it like this)
for (i = 0 ; i < R.rows * R.cols; ++i)
{    // you have to write the following :-)
     your_code(r[i]);
}
```

Comment: This will give me  pixel values (red) from the first row , right ?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I can see from cv::split() internals the second row is going to continue on from the first image with no padding. You can use `R.isContinuous()` to check whether this is true. Therefore `r` is not just a pointer to the first row, it is a pointer to the whole image data. Generally I wouldn't expose the structure of the image like this, without a very good reason.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there:

```
std::vector<Mat> planes(3);
cv::split(img, planes);
cv::Mat R = planes[2];
int r[20]; 
unsigned char *Rbuff = R.data;
for (i=0 ; i<20 ; i++)

{

r[i]= (int)Rbuff[i];

}
```

Comment: Using `memcpy()` instead of deferencing each pixel is safer, as it will avoid "bad alignment" errors in some architechtures.

Comment: @KeillRandor, for this answer the pixel data are uchars, how can they be misaligned? And for my answer where the pixel data are ints, OpenCV allocates buffers on 16 byte boundaries so they can't be misaligned either. Also it is a bit hard to do a type cast with `memcpy()`. On which architecture will this not work?