# How to extract r g b color components in an image using c++

Tags: opencv

I am doing a project on image encryption and decryption. So I need to extract RGB Color components in a color image. Please clear my doubt in open cv using c++. Thanks in advance.
Deepak Chiradoni

Comment: You left out a ton of information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932893/accessing-certain-pixel-rgb-value-in-opencv

Answer (score 0):

first load your image as

```
 Mat img=imread(file_name);
```

It returns img in BGR format. 
Now use following code snippet to access color components in BGR  image. here y-row index and x-column index

```
Vec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
uchar green = intensity.val[1];
uchar red = intensity.val[2];
```

Reference: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html