# Accessing RGB values of all pixels in a certain image in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, pixel

I have searched internet and stackoverflow thoroughly, but I didn't find what exactly I'm looking for!

How can I get RGB (BGR actually) values of a certain image (all pixels of the image) in OpenCV? I'm using C++, the image is stored in cv::Mat variable.

I'm showing some of my efforts so far: I tried this code from another stackoverflow link. But every time I re-run the code the value in Hexadecimal changed! For example once its 00CD5D7C, in next run it is 00C09D7C.

```
cv::Mat img_rgb = cv::imread("img6.jpg");
Point3_<uchar>* p = img_rgb.ptr<Point3_<uchar> >(10,10);
p->x; //B
p->y; //G
p->z; //R
std::cout<<p;
```

In another try I used this code from another answer. Here output is always -858993460.

```
img_rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(10,10);
img_rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(10,10)[0] = newval[0];
img_rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(10,10)[1] = newval[1];
img_rgb.at<cv::Vec3b>(10,10)[2] = newval[2];

cout<<newval[0]; //For cout<<newval[1]; cout<<newval[2]; the result is still same
```

NOTE: I used (10,10) as a test to get the RGB, my target is get the RGB values if the whole image!

Comment: It seems that you're not even trying to understand what you're doing. Use `std::cout << img_rgb.at<Vec3b>(10,10);`

Comment: @Miki Didn't realize I'm this much stupid! Thanks for the answer :) It works really fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing certain pixel RGB value in openCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932893/accessing-certain-pixel-rgb-value-in-opencv)

Comment: @TylerH that solution didn't work out for me, neither the explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading a color image (of type `CV_8UC3`), you need to access its elements with `.at<Vec3b>(row, col)`. The elements are in BGR order:

```
Mat img_bgr = imread("path_to_img");

for(int r = 0; r < img_bgr.rows; ++r) {
    for(int c = 0; c < img_bgr.cols; ++c) {
        std::cout << "Pixel at position (x, y) : (" << c << ", " << r << ") =" <<
             img_bgr.at<Vec3b>(r,c) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can also simplify using `Mat3b` (aka `Mat_<Vec3b>`), so you don't need to use the `.at` function, but using directly the parenthesis:

```
Mat3b img_bgr = imread("path_to_img");

for(int r = 0; r < img_bgr.rows; ++r) {
    for(int c = 0; c < img_bgr.cols; ++c) {
        std::cout << "Pixel at position (x, y) : (" << c << ", " << r << ") =" <<
             img_bgr(r,c) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

To get each single channel, you can easily do:

```
 Vec3b pixel = img_bgr(r,c); // or img_bgr.at<Vec3b>(r,c)
 uchar blue = pixel[0];
 uchar green = pixel[1];
 uchar red = pixel[2];
```

Comment: Nice explanation Sir, thanks a lot! And I found your email address, I think I'm gonna bother you more in near future as a newbie in Computer Vision.

Comment: @TousifZaman Please consider posting future questions on StackOverflow rather than in an e-mail so that the community can benefit from the responses as well.

Comment: @merlinND Sure, my questions will always come here. I'll knock him about some techniques and tips and suggestions in this field. StackOverflow is not a place for those I think.

Comment: @Miki LOL no problem, and I already posted a new question! Please take a look :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41807386/setting-rgb-values-of-pixels-in-a-certain-image-in-opencv