# Setting RGB values of pixels in a certain image in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to set RGB values of some pixels in a binary image. But whenever the coordinate is more than (89, 89) its giving me an assertion error! My image resolution is okay because I am accessing RGB values from (150, 150) coordinate. If the coordinate is (89, 89) or less it works fine. My Code:

```
cv::Mat img_gray, img_bw;
//read an image
cv::Mat3b img_bgr = cv::imread("test.jpg");
cv::imshow("Original Image", img_bgr);

//conversion to binary from color
cv::cvtColor(img_bgr, img_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
cv::threshold(img_gray, img_bw, 75.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY);

//accessing BGR of position (150, 150) from a color image
std::cout<<"Pixel at position (x, y) : ("<<150<<", "<<150<<") ="<<img_bgr(150,150)<<std::endl;  

//Setting BGR of position (150, 150) in binary image
img_bw.at<Vec3b>(150, 150)[0] = 255;
img_bw.at<Vec3b>(150, 150)[1] = 255;
img_bw.at<Vec3b>(150, 150)[2] = 255;
std::cout<<"Pixel at position (x, y) : ("<<150<<", "<<150<<") ="<<img_bw.at<Vec3b>(150, 150)<<std::endl;
```

Here if I put 89 instead of 150 in the "Setting BGR" section then it works. Otherwise the full error is:

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7stU0.jpg)*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file e:\opencv\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 538

So is this any type of memory space error?
Thanks in advance for the helps! :)

UPDATE: I've tried it this way! But the output is blank now.

```
cv::Mat img_gray, img_bw;
//read an image
cv::Mat3b img_bgr = cv::imread("test.jpg");
cv::imshow("Original Image", img_bgr);

//conversion to binary from color
cv::cvtColor(img_bgr, img_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
cv::threshold(img_gray, img_bw, 75.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY);

//accessing BGR of position (150, 150) from a color image
std::cout<<"Pixel at position (x, y) : ("<<150<<", "<<150<<") ="<<img_bgr(150,150)<<std::endl;  

//Setting BGR of position (150, 150) in binary image
img_bw.at<uchar>(150, 150) = 255;
std::cout<<"Pixel at position (x, y) : ("<<150<<", "<<150<<") ="<<img_bw.at<uchar>(150, 150)<<std::endl;
```

My test image is here

[image: This is my test image here]

And the output is here

[image: Output image here]

Comment: Your img_bw is of type gray. So you cannot access any pixel by typing img_bw.at<Vec3b>. You should use instead img_bw.at<ucahr>(150,150) = 255

Comment: @alex I tried that already. In that case my std::cout<<img_bw.at<ucahr>(150,150) is simply blank!

Comment: @TousifZaman We cannot fix code you do not show us. You know that using `Vec3b` is incorrect. If you show us your code using `uchar` along with the error and your input image, perhaps we can help you.

Comment: @TousifZaman Updates should be added to the question itself using [edit], not in the comments. We also still don't have your input image, so we cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @beaker Please check now. I hope it'll help you understand.

Comment: You're printing out a `<uchar>` with a value of `0` or `255`. Neither of these (in ascii or utf-8) are printable characters. Try assigning the pixel value to an int variable and then printing.

Comment: @beaker Thanks for the help, it works. Please put this into an answer so I can mark it up, it might help others. Also please vote up my question if you find this useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have the answer now thanks to beaker's hint in the comment :) I'm putting the solution for others help!

I just need to define the output as an integer. So the last cout will be like

```
std::cout<<"Pixel at position (x, y) : ("<<150<<", "<<150<<") ="<<(int)img_bw.at<uchar>(150, 150)<<std::endl;
```