# pixel conversion to raw bits (bit-stream)

Tags: c++, image-processing

I want to read the contents of every pixel in an image i have and convert it to a bit-stream (raw bits) or contain it in a 2-D array . Which would be the best place to start looking for such a conversion?

Specifics of the image : Standard test image called lena.bmp 
size : 256 x 256 
Bit depth of pixel : 8

Also I would like to know the importance of the number of bits per pixel with regards to this question since packing and unpacking will also be incorporated .

Comment: There's not much to convert, the BMP (DIB) format is more or less a raw dump of an array of pixel, prefixed with few headers that you can quickly find with a Google search.

Comment: I want to be able to write a program that converts the pixel value into hex and then into its consequent binary value and then store it in an array. Would OpenCV be a good option or is anything simpler recommended ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/index.html) is a nice simple, lightweight C++ library which can load and save a number of image formats (including BMP).

It's a single header file, so there's no need to compile or link the library. Just include the header, and you're good to go.

Comment: +1 I completely forgot about CImg, haven't used it in a while.

Comment: Hopefully this helps . I sincerely thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Cimg is pretty effective but i ended up using structs to define the bmp structure and used took a relatively longer approach to store pixel values into a 3d array but i chose a 24bit 512x512 which also works out for my project. Thank you so very much for ur advice.

Answer (score 2):

You should investigate [OpenCV](http://code.opencv.org/projects/OpenCV/wiki/WikiStart): a cross-platform computer vision library. It provides a **C++ API** as well as a **C API**, and it supports many image formats including **bmp**.

In the C++ interface, `cv::Mat` is the type that represents a 2D image. A simple application that loads and displays an image [can be found here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html#source-code).

To learn how to access the matrix elements (pixels) you can check these threads:

- [OpenCV get pixel information from Mat image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7903042/176769)
- [Pixel access in OpenCV 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4745323/176769)
- [Common Matrix Operations in OpenCV](http://mablresearch.rit.edu/wiki/index.php/Common_Matrix_Operations_in_OpenCV)

[OpenCV’s C++ interface](http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/opencvs-c-interface/) offers a short introduction to `cv::Mat`. There has been many threads on Stackoverflow regarding OpenCV, there's a lot of valuable content around and you can benefit a lot by using the search box.

[This page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome/Introduction) has a collection of books/tutorials/install guides focused on OpenCV, but [this the newest official tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/opencv_tutorials.pdf).

Comment: Isn't a big, complex Computer Vision library a tiiiny bit overkill for someone who just wants to access the pixels of a .bmp?

Comment: On Linux, the OpenCV libraries occupy less then 16MB. I don't know much space you have in your device, but I wouldn't call it big. About it being complex, I strongly disagree: [the test application](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html#source-code) to load/display an image shows how simple it can be making things a lot easier. It seems a little bit overkill to write the code to read the bmp header yourself when there are other ways.

Comment: Well, considering you can download a single, simple cross-platform header file which, if you include it, allows you to load a .bmp file, I think that a 16 MB library is pretty much the definition of overkill. ;)