# copying ipl image pixel by pixel

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv

The problem is solved....I used cvGet2D,below is the sample code

```
        CvScalar s;
        s=cvGet2D(src_Image,pixel[i].x,pixel[i].y);         
        cvSet2D(dst_Image,pixel[i].x,pixel[i].y,s);
```

Where src_Iamge and dst_Image is the source and destination image correspondingly and pixel[i] is the selected pixel i wanted to draw in the dst image. I have include the real out image below.

have an source Ipl image, I want to copy some of the part of the image to a new destination image pixel by pixel. can any body tell me how can do it? I use c,c++ in opencv. For example if the below image is source image,  [image]

The real output image[image]

Comment: Well, you could do it just as you described, I mean an IplImage has a pointer to the data, and you could just manually implement something to copy a ROI.

Comment: I don't want to set ROI i want to copy some of the pixels and show it in the output image.

Comment: You can use [`cvGet2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvget2d#get-d)

Comment: Thank Sgar..I am also thinking of using cvGet2D..I will let you know if it works...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I can see the comments suggesting cvGet2d. I think, if you just want to show "points", it is best to show them with a small neighbourhood so they can be seen where they are. For that you can draw white filled circles with origins at (x,y), on a mask, then you do the `copyTo`.

```
using namespace cv;

Mat m(input_iplimage);
Mat mask=Mat::zeros(m.size(), CV_8UC1);

p1 = Point(x,y); 
r = 3;
circle(mask,p1,r, 1); // draws the circle around your point.
floodFill(mask, p1, 1); // fills the circle.

//p2, p3, ...

Mat output = Mat::zeros(m.size(),m.type()); // output starts with a black background.
m.copyTo(output, mask); // copies the selected parts of m to output
```

OLD post:

Create a mask and copy those pixels:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

Mat m(input_iplimage);
Mat mask=Mat::zeros(m.size(), CV_8UC1); // set mask 1 for every pixel you wanna copy.
Rect roi=Rect(x,y,width,height);  // create a rectangle
mask(roi) = 1;   // set it to 0.
roi = Rect(x2,y2,w2,h2);
mask(roi)=1;     // set the second rectangular area for copying...

Mat output = 100*Mat::ones(m.size(),m.type()); // output with a gray background.
m.copyTo(output, mask); // copy selected areas of m to output
```

Alternatively you can copy Rect-by-Rect:

```
Mat m(input_iplimage);
Mat output = 100*Mat::ones(m.size(),m.type()); // output with a gray background.

Rect roi=Rect(x,y,width,height);
Mat m_temp, out_temp;
m_temp=m(roi);
out_temp = output(roi);
m_temp.copyTo(out_temp);

roi=Rect(x2,y2,w2,h2);
Mat m_temp, out_temp;
m_temp=m(roi);
out_temp = output(roi);
m_temp.copyTo(out_temp);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't want to do ROI as it takes rect wise. suppose From the source image I know information about 20 pixels (x,y position information) I want to show this pixels in their real shape(may be polygon but not rectangle). But if I use ROI i will have to show a rectangle.

Comment: well, I have shown you how you can assemble masks, too. (see "create a mask") And it is up to you what shape you draw in that. (If you draw a white filled circle into the mask, you will see circles...)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question only requires to have look at the OpenCV documentation or just to search in your favourite search engine.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742251/pixel-access-in-opencv-2-2) you've an answer for Ipl images and for newer Mat data.

For having an output as I see in your images, I'd do it setting ROI's, it's more efficient.

Comment: thanks for your opinion..but I don't want to use ROI.Suppose I know info about only 10 pixels and they are in round or some other shape..I want to show their real shape.If I use ROI then I have to show as a rectangle.

Comment: well, in the answer that I posted you can find a code to copy pixel per pixel that allows you to do that.