# Mat access element OpenCV2.3

Tags: opencv, matrix

I've read a few posts about Mat element access and had some trials but all failed. Could someone give me a hint?

```
Mat vect(1,3, CV_32FC1);     
typedef Vec<float,1> Vec1f;  //**
// access ele. at (1,1)
vect.at<Vec1f>( Point(1,1 )) = 5;  // I used 1 channel so I defined a new element type as a workaround
```

I adapted the code from this post 
[opencv multi channel element access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824787/opencv-multi-channel-element-access/1836580#1836580)

And, I though thet line //** can be declared like:

```
typedef Vec<float> Vec1f;
```

according to line 582 in core.hpp: Vec(_Tp v0); //!< 1-element vector constructor

However, it also doesn't work

I applied the same method for 2D matrix then it is fine:

```
Mat warp_mat(2,3, CV_32FC1);
typedef Vec<float,1> Vec1f;

warp_mat.at<Vec1f>( Point(0,0 )) = 1;
warp_mat.at<Vec1f>( Point(1,0 )) = 2;
warp_mat.at<Vec1f>( Point(2,0 )) = 5;
warp_mat.at<Vec1f>( Point(0,1 )) = 4;
warp_mat.at<Vec1f>( Point(1,1 )) = 5;
warp_mat.at<Vec1f>( Point(2,1 )) = 0;
```

it works OK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://aishack.in/tutorials/opencvs-c-interface/

> Mat a= Mat(4,3, CV_32FC1);
>
> float elem_a= a.at(i,j); //access element aij, with i from 0 to
>   rows-1 and j from 0 to cols-1

Comment: actually, I've tried 'at' function but it does not work this way. The one that works is: frame.at<uchar>(30,10). Type, here is uchar, must be put at front.

Comment: Another problem I'm having is: that matrix is a real image with 3 channels   matrix.at<uchar>(i,j)  gives access to element i,j but which channel?? how can I access each channel I want??

Comment: "If you’re dealing with a multi-channel Mat, things are a little more complex. But still easier than the CV_MAT_ELEM or CV_IMAGE_ELEM macros. You must use the ptr method to obtain a pointer to a particular row. Then you use the [] to access a particular pixel in a particular channel:"

type elem = matrix.ptr<type>(i)[N<sub>c</sub>*j+c]

Comment: my current choice is using "at" of Mat matrix. It works pretty OK