# Accessing elements in a multi-channel OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rgb, cielab

this is my first post on stackoverflow, so I hope to do everything right, sorry if I don't.

I'm writing code for a function to convert a single RGB value into CIE L*a*b* color space. The function is supposed to take a 3 floats array (RGB channels with values in [0-255]) and to give in output a 3 floats array with the L*a*b* values. To do so, I'm using the [`cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#creating-a-mat-object-explicitly) function available with OpenCV.

As suggested on [the openCV website](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#creating-a-mat-object-explicitly) I'm creating the Mat structures (needed by `cvtColor`) by contructor.

My problem is that, although I think the code runs properly and performs the conversion, I'm unable to get the values contained in the Mat structure back.

Here's my code:

```
float * rgb2lab(float rgb[3]) {
    // bring input in range [0,1]
    rgb[0] = rgb[0] / 255;
    rgb[1] = rgb[1] / 255;
    rgb[2] = rgb[2] / 255;

    // copy rgb in Mat data structure and check values
    cv::Mat rgb_m(1, 1, CV_32FC3, cv::Scalar(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]));
    std::cout << "rgb_m = " << std::endl << " " << rgb_m << std::endl;
    cv::Vec3f elem = rgb_m.at<cv::Vec3f>(1, 1);
    float R = elem[0];
    float G = elem[1];
    float B = elem[2];
    printf("RGB =\n [%f, %f, %f]\n", R, G, B);

    // create lab data structure and check values
    cv::Mat lab_m(1, 1, CV_32FC3, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    std::cout << "lab_m = " << std::endl << " " << lab_m << std::endl;

    // convert
    cv::cvtColor(rgb_m, lab_m, CV_RGB2Lab);

    // check lab value after conversion
    std::cout << "lab_m2 = " << std::endl << " " << lab_m << std::endl;
    cv::Vec3f elem2 = lab_m.at<cv::Vec3f>(1, 1);
    float l = elem2[0];
    float a = elem2[1];
    float b = elem2[2];
    printf("lab =\n [%f, %f, %f]\n", l, a, b);

    // generate the output and return
    static float lab[] = { l, a, b };
    return lab;
}
```

As you can see, I'm extracting all channels from the Mat structure by the `at` function and then accessing them individually from the vector. This is proposed as the solution in many places ([one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824787/opencv-multi-channel-element-access)).

But if I run this code (input vector was {123,10,200}), on `cout` I correctly get the outputs of the Mat structures (from which I get the algorithm is converting correctly), but as you can see the extracted values are wrong:

```
rgb_m = 
 [0.48235294, 0.039215688, 0.78431374]
RGB =
 [0.000000, 0.000000, -5758185472.000000]
lab_m = 
 [0, 0, 0]
lab_m2 = 
 [35.198029, 70.120964, -71.303688]
lab =
 [0.000000, 0.000000, 4822177514157213323960797626368.000000]
```

Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: You do right access, but indexes are wrong. Matrix indexes start with 0, so to access first element you need something like `rgb_m.at<cv::Vec3f>(0, 0)`

Comment: The problem seems to be the (1,1), first element of the Mat is at (0,0), as for vector

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I cannot believe I've done such a stupid mistake. Since all the guides I saw used the (1,1) notation, I thought this was using the "Matlab" convention about indexes... thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element of a `cv::Mat` is always at `(0, 0)`, so just correct `cv::Vec3f elem = rgb_m.at<cv::Vec3f>(1, 1);` by `cv::Vec3f elem = rgb_m.at<cv::Vec3f>(0, 0);` and `cv::Vec3f elem2 = lab_m.at<cv::Vec3f>(1, 1);` by `cv::Vec3f elem2 = lab_m.at<cv::Vec3f>(0, 0);`